# Existe "outrens"?

Tags: pronomes, número-gramatical, pronomes-indefinidos

Pela minha pesquisa, o plural de "alguém" é "alguéns". Depois disso, eu pensei sobre o plural doutras palavras que envolvem "alguém", "outrem" e "ninguém", e pensei "será que esses têm plural?". O plural de "ninguém" não faria muito sentido - já que "ninguém" é igual a "0 pessoas"-, mas o plural de "outrem" faria sentido e lógica de acordo com "alguém". Porém, eu não encontrei nada sobre o plural de "outrem", mas isso não afirma sua inexistência.

Resumo da ópera: existe "outrens", tendo em vista que "alguéns" está correto? E se não existe, isso me impede de usá-lo?

Comment: «O plural de "ninguém" não faria muito sentido» Pois, só que o português gosta de fazer batota e arranjar maneiras de contornar as regras: um zé-ninguém, dois zé-**ninguéns**. :)

Comment: @ANeves, nesse caso faria sentido, mas **ninguém** sozinho não faria sentido. Edição: talvez **"ninguéns"** poderia dar ênfase.

Comment: Sim, tens razão que não faria sentido. Mas o plural existe. :) Como existe a primeira pessoa singular do presente de "[chover](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/chover)", por causa de chover no molhado... :) adoro estas pequenas batotices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outrem é um pronome indefinido invariável, logo não aceita plural e nem modifica o gênero.